# Definition for Euler characteristic without CW-complexes

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

It is possible to have a definition of the Euler characteristic without using CW-complexes? (I'm referring to the definition given by Wikipedia :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition.)

What is the geometrical picture behind these numbers, of there is any?

Comment: The Euler characteristic can be defined as an alternating sum of Betti numbers. (This is the third paragraph in your link.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as we can take singular homology (which we can for all topological spaces), then we define the Betti numbers to be the ranks of the individual homology groups and then if the alternating sum of Betti numbers of the space is finite, then we define the Euler characteristic to be this alternating sum. The Euler characteristic is undefined if this alternating sum does not converge - this definition can be extended to include other spaces but at the cost of properties of the Euler characteristic.

With regard to your geometric picture question, the Euler characteristic is mostly a book-keeping tool, although it certainly is related to geometric properties, mostly through the [genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29#) of a surface, but also in how we can manipulate the Euler characteristic through, for example, disjoint union which corresponds to addition of Euler characteristic. We also have that the wedge product corresponds to addition minus 1, the product of spaces corresponds to the product of Euler characteristics, and more generally this holds for a fibration where the Euler characteristic of the total space is the product of the Euler characteristics of the base space and fiber.

Comment: Can you give an example for which the Euler characteristic is thus defined does not converge? Does this has a specific meaning or can the Euler characteristic be redefined for such pathological cases ?

Comment: Well the easiest example I guess would be the disjoint union of every dimensional sphere $\bigsqcup_i S^i$, or maybe the infinite dimensional complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ - although this case can be handled by allowing the Euler characteristic to take values of infinity and negative infinity.

Comment: I should also add that we can in fact even define something like an Euler characteristic for some spaces which have non-trivial homology in all dimensions (similar to how we can define the sum of some infinite divergent sequences such as Grandi's series), although we lose properties of the normal Euler characteristic such as taking integer values.